# WPF Dispatcher BeginInvoke ordering guarantee

Tags: c#, wpf

If I call

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(operation, DispatcherPriority.Loaded)
```

1,000,000 times from over 20 threads, are those 1,000,000 operations guranteed to be **executed by the UI thread** in the order the BeginInvoke calls were made?

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?

Comment: It looks like operation is a delegate of some sort.  Could you just use a queue and only have one process actually invoking them?

Comment: I need the delegates to be executed on the UI thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

msdn says that [If multiple BeginInvoke calls are made at the same DispatcherPriority, they will be executed in the order the calls were made](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591587.aspx)

But if you are accessing the `Dispatcher` from multiple thread then [Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615907.aspx)

Comment: @BrokenGlass: how could it be? `Dispatcher` manages a single thread. If one operation starts on that thread it will be executed till the end before another operation will be started. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess I should have looked at the BeginInvoke doc. :)